# Target iframe if it is a YouTube embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I want to wrap all YouTube embeds on the page into a div. Currently, I can wrap **all** iframes in a div with:

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('iframe').wrap("<div class='ta-vid-cont'></div>");

   });
```

But I want to target only iframes that are YouTube Embeds. How can I do this?

Typical YouTube embed looks like:

```
<iframe width="700" height="394" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d3LDQMKLc?feature=oembed&wmode=transparent">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use `Attrubute Contains` selector

```
$('iframe[src*="youtube"]').wrap("<div class='ta-vid-cont'></div>");
```

Reference [Attribute Contains Selector docs](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

you could use filter() in combination with a regex filtering via the source url:

```
jQuery('iframe').filter(function(){
    return this.src.match(/youtube\.com/i);
}).wrap("<div class='ta-vid-cont'></div>");
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0hhk9kc5/1/

(since jsfiddle won't show iframes for security reasons, i changed the filtering to another attribute...but the idea is the same ;) )

**[EDIT]:** for covering youtu.be:

```
jQuery('iframe').filter(function(){
    return this.src.match(/(youtube\.com|youtu\.be)/i);
}).wrap("<div class='ta-vid-cont'></div>");
```

explanation of the used regex: https://regex101.com/r/dU0bF2/1

Comment: Interesting, although sometimes the URL is: **youtu.be** -- can I adjust the code to target both cases?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can search in src attribute of iframe for "www.youtube.com"

```
var str=$('iframe').attr('src');  
if(str.search('www.youtube.com') > 0){  
......
....  
};
```

Regards

Comment: won't work because `$('iframe').attr('src')` only returns value of first iframe in page. Would have to be in a loop and target specific instances

Comment: To get all iframe you can use $( "iframe" ).each(function() { var str=$(this).attr('src');
if(str.search('www.youtube.com') > 0){
...... ....
}; });

Comment: no ...the selector will return all iframe... but the `attr()` as getter can only return one value...and that is the first one in collection

Answer (score 0):

you can easily assign each iframe an id and grab it with jQuery`<iframe id="youtube" width="700" height="394" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d3LDQMKLc?feature=oembed&wmode=transparent">`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#youtube').wrap("<div class='ta-vid-cont'></div>");
});
```