# modify script that adds wrapper class to iframes - make it only apply to certain domains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a little custom script made a number of years ago that applies a wrapper with class "mbed" to all iframes except those with the class "nombed".

```
$("iframe").each(function(){
    var parent=$(this).parent();
    if(!parent.hasClass('mbed') && !parent.hasClass('nombed') && !$(this).hasClass('nombed') ){
        $(this).wrap("<div class='mbed'></div>");
    }
});
```

The script used to work fine 100% of the time but have found recently it a little problematic. Even with a wrapper div with the class "nombed", some third party iframes behave badly to the point of breaking pages. Others look wrong visually by applying the mbed class when they shouldn't (eg the mbed class might have a border and the nombed might not).

What I would like is for the script to be modified so that I can also specify which domains it works for (eg to only apply the mbed class to the domains specified in the script). Specifically at the moment for:

- youtube.com
- vimeo.com
- maps.googleapis.com.xxxx (where xxxx is an unknown api and may or may not be present)
- maps.google.com.xxxx (where xxxx is an unknown api and may or may not be present)

After doing some searching I found this solution [Target iframe if it is a YouTube embed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082785/target-iframe-if-it-is-a-youtube-embed) which helped me greatly and I managed (minor miracle believe me) to extend the original script to only work on the above 4 domains.

```
$('iframe[src*="youtube.com"],iframe[src*="vimeo.com"],iframe[src*="maps.googleapis.com"],iframe[src*="maps.google.com"]').each(function(){
    var parent=$(this).parent();
    if(!parent.hasClass('mbed') && !parent.hasClass('nombed') && !$(this).hasClass('nombed') ){
        $(this).wrap("<div class='mbed'></div>");
    }
});
```

The above is working which is great. But I am wondering if there is a way to neaten it up a bit / add the domains as variables (or whatever the terminology / best approach is) on separate lines so its easy to see the relevant domains at a glance, and easy to add new ones as relevant

```
$('iframe').each(function(){
    var parent=$(this).parent();

    //add the domains sort of like this in a way that works...
    src*="youtube.com"
    src*="vimeo.com"
    src*="maps.googleapis.com"
    src*="maps.google.com"        

    if(!parent.hasClass('mbed') && !parent.hasClass('nombed') && !$(this).hasClass('nombed') ){
        $(this).wrap("<div class='mbed'></div>");
    }
});
```

As you can probably tell I am not a coder and would greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try storing the domains in an array and then joining them:

```
var domains = [
    "youtube.com",
    "vimeo.com",
    "maps.googleapis.com",
    "maps.google.com"
];
var selector = domains.map(function (domain) { return 'iframe[src*="' + domain + '"]' }).join(','); 

$(selector).each(function(){
    var parent=$(this).parent();
    if(!parent.hasClass('mbed') && !parent.hasClass('nombed') && !$(this).hasClass('nombed') ){
        $(this).wrap("<div class='mbed'></div>");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Isaac, that works perfectly and is also exactly what I was hoping for. The script works fine but DreamWeaver throws a syntatx error on the 7th line "var selector..." - not sure why, do you? I will wait a bit longer to see other approaches before confirming the solution. Thank you again

Comment: It could be an es6 issue, it might not like the arrow functions. Try the edited solution now?

Comment: Thank you kindly Isaac, that fixed the DreamWeaver syntax error. Workes perfectly. Cheers

Comment: Both solutions worked great and were very similar. I chose this one because the domain listing is a little cleaner. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is something like this:

```
var domains = [
   'iframe[src*="youtube.com"]',
   'iframe[src*="vimeo.com"]',
   'iframe[src*="maps.googleapis.com"]',
   'iframe[src*="maps.google.com"]' 
];

$(domains.join(',')).each(function(){
    var parent=$(this).parent();
    if(!parent.hasClass('mbed') && !parent.hasClass('nombed') && !$(this).hasClass('nombed') ){
        $(this).wrap("<div class='mbed'></div>");
    }
});
```

It could be written more optimized, but it is a great way.

Comment: Thanks very much Yulio, that works perfectly and is exactly what I was hoping for. I might wait another couple of hours to see other approaches before confirming the solution. Thank you